# Eslint error in React app: 'default' is restricted from being used as an exported name.eslintno-restricted-exports

Tags: reactjs, typescript, components, eslint

For my components, I use the following structure in my React app:

```
atoms/
Button/
Button.tsx
Button.styles.ts
index.ts
// etc...
```

from `index.ts` I use:

```
export { default } from './Button';
```

Which allows me inside below file to have:
`from './Button';`

instead of:
`from './Button/Button';`

Inside `atoms/` folder I have another `index.ts` file:

```
export { default as Button } from './Button';
export { default as Checkbox } from './Checkbox'
// etc
```

Which allows me to import the Button component like:
`import { Button } from 'app/components/atoms';`

**Button.tsx:**

```
const Button = (props: Props) => {
  return (
    <button>
      {props.text}
    </button>
  );
};


export default Button;
```

After updating Eslint I get the following error from `src/app/components/atoms/Button/index.tsx`:

> 'default' is restricted from being used as an exported
> name.eslintno-restricted-exports

How do I fix this?

Comment: Consider changing `eslintno-restricted-exports` option